# Adjusting Resolution of DICOM Images

Tags: matlab, dicom, imaging, medical

I am working with DICOM images, and would like to change the resolution of all the images I have to 0.5mm/pixel. What are the entries that I should access in the DICOM header and how can I change the resolution?

Thank you,

Comment: Try updating the pixel spacing related tag such as Imager Pixel Spacing (0018, 1164), Pixel Spacing (0028, 0030) etc.

Comment: It says, "Reference to non-existent field". I'm afraid pixel spacing information does not exist in my DICOM header. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Do you have data which is 0.5mm/pixel and want to adjust the header to reflect that, or do you need to resample the actual image?

Comment: I need to resample my images to obtain 0.5mm/pixel. It is that I am working on a database and performing the preprocessing stage by giving all my images a fixed spatial resolution.

Answer (score 1):

What is the SOP Class of your DICOM dataset? Assuming you are dealing with volumetric SOP class which should include Image Plane module. In that case, Pixel Spacing (0028, 0030) is a mandatory type 1 element and should be present in the dataset.  You can also add the attribute to the dataset and set the values yourself. 
Please note that all pixel spacing related attributes are encoded as the physical distance between the centers of each two dimensional pixel, specified by two numeric values in mm. The first value is the spacing between the centers of adjacent rows (row spacing) and second value is the is the spacing between the centers of adjacent columns (column spacing).